# Updating an element after page load when another element is visible

Tags: javascript

I apologize for not know exactly how to ask this question but, here it goes.

I have an image slider that only loads images as they are needed, so they do not all exist in the dom when the page is loaded. Having said that I need to write a conditional that displays an element based on when a certain image becomes visible on the page. The problem is since the photo doesn't exist in the DOM when the page is loaded I can't use jQuery to take care of this for me. Does anyone know what I need to do to get this done?

Here is the html, where i'm trying to listen for  `<img src="http://example.com/images/HOME_PAGE/1.jpg">` to be loaded:

```
<div class="galleria-images" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
  <div class="galleria-image" style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 0; -webkit-transition: none; transition: none; z-index: 0; width: 1038px; height: 575px;">
    <div class="galleria-layer" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; z-index: 2; display: none;"></div>
    <img src="http://example.com/images/HOME_PAGE/2.jpg" style="display: block; opacity: 1; min-width: 0px; min-height: 0px; max-width: none; max-height: none; width: 1038px; height: 583px; position: absolute; top: -4px; left: 0px;" width="1038" height="583">
  </div>
  <div class="galleria-image" style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 1; width: 1038px; height: 575px; -webkit-transition: none; transition: none; z-index: 1;">
    <div class="galleria-layer" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; z-index: 2; display: none;"></div>
    <img src="http://example.com/images/HOME_PAGE/1.jpg" style="display: block; opacity: 1; min-width: 0px; min-height: 0px; max-width: none; max-height: none; width: 1038px; height: 583px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;" width="1038" height="583">
  </div>
</div>
```

Once I see that image loaded I was trying to add a "Play Button" overlay using jQuery, but obviously I'm having trouble since every image is being loaded after page load.

Here is the JS that loads the images:

```
(function (a) {
    Galleria.addTheme({
        name: "classic",
        author: "Galleria",
        css: "galleria.classic.css",
        defaults: {
            transition: "slide",
            thumbCrop: "height",
            _toggleInfo: !0
        },
        init: function (b) {
            Galleria.requires(1.25, "This version of Classic theme requires Galleria 1.2.5 or later"), this.addElement("info-link", "info-close"), this.append({
                info: ["info-link", "info-close"]
            });
            var c = this.$("info-link,info-close,info-text"),
                d = Galleria.TOUCH,
                e = d ? "touchstart" : "click";
            this.$("loader,counter").show().css("opacity", .4), d || (this.addIdleState(this.get("image-nav-left"), {
                left: -50
            }), this.addIdleState(this.get("image-nav-right"), {
                right: -50
            }), this.addIdleState(this.get("counter"), {
                opacity: 0
            })), b._toggleInfo === !0 ? c.bind(e, function () {
                c.toggle()
            }) : (c.show(), this.$("info-link, info-close").hide()), this.bind("thumbnail", function (b) {
                d ? a(b.thumbTarget).css("opacity", this.getIndex() ? 1 : .6) : (a(b.thumbTarget).css("opacity", .6).parent().hover(function () {
                    a(this).not(".active").children().stop().fadeTo(100, 1)
                }, function () {
                    a(this).not(".active").children().stop().fadeTo(400, .6)
                }), b.index === this.getIndex() && a(b.thumbTarget).css("opacity", 1))
            }), this.bind("loadstart", function (b) {
                b.cached || this.$("loader").show().fadeTo(200, .4), this.$("info").toggle(this.hasInfo()), a(b.thumbTarget).css("opacity", 1).parent().siblings().children().css("opacity", .6)
            }), this.bind("loadfinish", function (a) {
                this.$("loader").fadeOut(200)
            })
        }
    })
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you tried to use body.onload, document.ready, image.onload? Onload action for image you need to append immediately after image created.

Comment: You need to give us more info, i.e. describe your current setup, your requirements and the problem in more detail.

Comment: I updated, sorry about that @ExpertSystem

Comment: @fentech: Where is the code that loads the images ? (BTW, put CSS in a file instead of using inline styling (i.e. `style` tags.)

Comment: @ExpertSystem that is part of the extension i am using for joomla, all of my personal styling are in CSS files

Comment: @ExpertSystem: It's now updated with JS

Comment: @fentech: Is there a demo of the site in question publicly available to take a look. It is still unclear what takes place in the DOM.

Comment: @ExpertSystem thisisvisual.com

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40078/discussion-between-fentech-and-expertsystem)

Comment: @fentech: Did you try my suggestion below ? Did if work for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your slideshow library is adding and removing `img` nodes in the DOM, you can use a **[MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)** to listen for those changes and check for the events that interest you (i.e. adding an `img` node with `src="http://example.com/images/HOME_PAGE/1.jpg"`).

**Sample code:**
(based on html structure at [thisisvisual.com](http://thisisvisual.com))

```
var imgToLookFor = "http://example.com/images/HOME_PAGE/1.jpg";
var parentNodeToWatch = document.querySelector("#jbArticle");

// Create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(checkForImage);
});

// Start observing the parent node and 
//its descendants for <childList> changes
observer.observe(parentNodeToWatch, {
    "childList": true,
    "subtree": true
});

// Check MutationRecords to detect when our image is added
function checkForImage(mutation) {
    if (mutation.addedNodes && (mutation.addedNodes.length > 0)) {
        // There where nodes added, lets check them out one-by-one
        [].slice.call(mutation.addedNodes).forEach(function(node) {
            if ((node.nodeName == "IMG") && node.src
                    && (node.src == imgToLookFor)) {
                alert("Don't just look at me !\n"
                      + "Do something, will ya ?");
            }
        });
    }
}
```