# How do I have jQuery do something when Facebook posts autoload, rather than just when the page loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension to remove certain posts from Facebook feeds. I'm using jQuery, and I've got something like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var post = $('.fbTimelineUnit');

    post.remove();

        }
    );
```

This removes the first posts that load, but others just autoload and occupy the space the removed posts did. Say I want to remove all posts as they come in. How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a **[MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)** to listen for changes (i.e. child additions) in the posts' parent element. (I don't know much about FB, so you have to figure out the details yourself.)

Somethin like this:

```
var postsContainer = ...
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        // ...if it's a new post delete/remove/hide it somehow
    });    
});
observer.observe(postsContainer, {childList: true, subtree: true });

// When done:
observer.disconnect();
```

---

To get you started, here are some (simple to not so simple) examples of using a MutationObserver in an extension:

- **[Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560819/chrome-extension-fire-an-event-when-element-created#answer-19767155)**
- **[Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621553/updating-an-element-after-page-load-when-another-element-is-visible#answer-19629700)**
- **[Example 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042852/chrome-extension-to-parse-google-results-doesnt-work#answer-19779517)**